# C++ if statement error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign `bool leapyear` to `true/false` if the requirements of if statement are met

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int month;
    int year;
    bool leapyear;
    cout << "Enter a month (1-12): ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Enter a year: ";
    cin >> year;

    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
        cout << "31 days\n";
    }
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        cout << "30 day\n";
    }

    if ((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)) {
        bool leapyear = true;
        cout << "This year is a leap year!\n";
    }
    else {
        bool leapyear = false;
        cout << "This year is not a leap year!\n";
    }

    if (leapyear == true && month == 2) {
        cout << "29 days\n";
    }
    else if (leapyear == false && month == 2) {
        cout << "28 days\n";
    }
}
```

but when I run the code visual showed me an error

```
 Uninitialized local variable 'leapyear' used
```

Comment: `bool leapyear = true;` creates a new variable with the same name. Use `leapyear = true;` instead.

Comment: You're declaring `leapyear` again inside 2 of your conditional conditions,

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what the issue is.  The leapyear inside your if statement is actually a completely new variable.

Comment: @AnonMail the error message does not tell exactly what is the issue. The error message is about a symptom of the mistake OP made (using unitialized variable), but if OP doesnt know what is the cause (declaring variables with same names), then the error message also wont help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the two `bool` in your `if` and `else` blocks and give an initial value to your `leapyear` variable. You are trying to define a variable with the same name several times instead of just changing its value, which is probably what you want to do here.

Initialization:

```
int month;
int year;
bool leapyear = false; // You have to initialize the value of your variable here.
```

If and else statements:

```
if ((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)) {
    leapyear = true;
    cout << "This year is a leap year!\n";
}
else {
    leapyear = false;
    cout << "This year is not a leap year!\n";
}
```

You have to understand the difference between creating a variable and setting its value.

```
bool leapyear = false; // Create a leapyear variable with the initial value false
leapyear = true; // Modify the value of the leapyear variable with the value true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has three different variables, all called `leapyear`, and each that exists for a different part of the code.

At the top of your program, you declared `leapyear`:

```
int month;
int year;
bool leapyear; // This variable is not initialized.
```

Down later, you declare more variable2, also called `leapyear`:

```
 if ((year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)) {
        // New Variable declared here!
        // It has the same name, but is a different variable
        bool leapyear = true;
        cout << "This year is a leap year!\n";
        // The local variable ends here
        // It goes "out-of-scope", and no longer exists.
    }                           
    else {
        // New Variable declared here!
        bool leapyear = false;
        cout << "This year is not a leap year!\n";
        // The Variable goes "out-of-scope" here, and no longer exists.
    }
```

Later on, when your code does this:

```
 // Using the original variable, which is STILL not initialized
 if (leapyear == true && month == 2) {  
        cout << "29 days\n";
    }
    else if (leapyear == false && month == 2) {
        cout << "28 days\n";
    }
```